# A Combinations Problem Involving Days Of the Week

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, problem-solving

I'am reading through *Engineering Math* by Ken Stroud/Dexter Booth and in page 274 under *Combinations*. Here's the situation.

Assuming that you have a part-time Job in the weekday evenings where you have to be at work just two evenings out of the five. Let's also assume that your employer is very flexible and allows you to choose which evenings you work provided you ring him up on sunday and tell him. One possible selection could be:

Mon-Work Tue-Work

Another selection could be:

Wed-Work Fri-Work

So the possible arrangements among the five days is $$5 \cdot 4 = 20.$$

Because

There are $5$ weekdays from which to make a first selection and for each such 
selection there are $4$ days left from which to make the second selection. This 
gives a total of $5 \cdot 4 = 20$ possible arrangements. 
However, not all arrangements are different. For example, if, on the Sunday, 
you made your first choice as Friday and your second choice as Wednesday, 
this would be the same arrangement as making 
your first choice as Wednesday and your second choice as Friday. 
So every arrangement is duplicated. 
How many different arrangements are there?

$$\frac{5\cdot 4 }{ 2 }= 10.$$

And he says it's

Because each arrangement is duplicated. List them:

Mon, Tue Mon, Wed Mon, Thu Mon, Fri

Tue, Wed Tue, Thu Tue, Fri

Wed, Thu Wed, Fri

Thu, Fri

There are $10$ different ways of combining two identical items in five different 
places.

The expression $$ \frac{5 \cdot 4}{2}$$  can be written in factorial form as follows.

$$\frac{5 \cdot 4}{2} = \frac{5\cdot 4}{2\cdot 1} = 
\frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{(3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1)(2\cdot 1)} = \frac{5!}{3!2!}.$$

He ends by saying, if your employer asked you to work $3$ evenings out of the $5$, how many 
different arrangements could you select? (Give your answer in terms of 
factorials.)

$$\frac{5!}{(5-3)!3!}.$$

Ok My question is Why on earth should i ever write $$\frac{5 \cdot 4}{2} = 10$$ in factorial form as it's written above  with additional natural numbers and end that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course for small cases you can make do with your notation. But instead, consider the case where you have to select all your working days for the next year of, say, $40$ weeks. Then the problem comes down to selecting $80$ out of $200$ options. Then the formula becomes

$$\frac{200\cdot199\cdot198\cdot\ldots\cdot121}{80\cdot79\cdot78\cdot\ldots\cdot1}$$

Instead, in this case the notation of the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) lets you write this expression in a shorter form:

$$\frac{200\cdot199\cdot198\cdot\ldots\cdot121}{80\cdot79\cdot78\cdot\ldots\cdot1} = \frac{200\cdot199\cdot198\cdot\ldots\cdot121}{80\cdot79\cdot78\cdot\ldots\cdot1} \cdot \frac{120\cdot119\cdot118\cdot\ldots\cdot1}{120\cdot119\cdot118\cdot\ldots\cdot1} = \frac{200!}{80!\cdot120!} = \binom{200}{80}$$

Answer (score 3):

Because if you want to describe a more general result, the factorials are convenient.  If you need to choose $r$ days to work out of $n$ days, the number of ways to choose is the number of [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinations), written as ${n \choose r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$.  This is hard to describe without the factorials.

Comment: Of course one can always write something like $\frac{n\times(n-1)\times\cdots\times(n-r+1)}{r\times(r-1)\times\cdots\times2\times 1}$, but that is certainly less _convenient_ -- and also carries a risk of mistakes because it leaves it to the reader to _guess_ what the dots are supposed to stand for. If one writes down too few of the terms explicitly, it might be that there there are several different guesses that all match -- and there is no way to be certain that one has enough terms, save for the rather risky "I myself can't imagine more than one interpretation".